# Different free disk space figures in df output after complete rsync -Sap transfer

Tags: rsync, mdadm

I did "rsync -Sap --numeric-ids --delete-during /mnt/RAIDVault/ /mnt/RAIDVault-BACKUP/" intending to bring two storage units in sync (having identical content) but ended up with different amount of free disk space on the two:

`/dev/md1        2.0T  2.0T   81G  96% /mnt/RAIDVault
 /dev/md0        2.0T  2.0T   79G  97% /mnt/RAIDVault-BACKUP
 /dev/md1       1951405544 1873160540  78245004  96% /mnt/RAIDVault
 /dev/md0       1951405544 1874906476  76499068  97% /mnt/RAIDVault-BACKUP`

I'm scratching my head here as I don't know why this happens nor where to start troubleshooting. There were no errors, rsync completed a transfer just fine, everything seems fine and "uptodate".

Yet somehow /dev/md0 is 2 gigabytes less after what was supposed to be a "mirror A to B" transfer.

The df output was produced with "df --sync". I think it's a reliable figure. df never lies, does it?

An important distinction between /dev/md0 and /dev/md1 is that even though both are raid1 type of software raid /dev/md0 has currently only 1 array member. I'm wondering if that's what causing different figures in df's report?

So, my question is two fold:

1. Why are there different figures in df's report?
2. How can you make sure both, md0 and md1, have complete and identical copies of the same contents?

Comment: Also, you may have different journal sizes, or different amount of reserved blocks (use `dumpe2fs` to see).

Comment: I do happen to have sparse files (virtualbox disk device images). That accounts for at least 1G in difference. The remaining 1G difference isn't immediately clear but I guess it can be explained if looked at thoroughly.

Comment: Just for the record: you did do `--sparse` so the target should have sparse files too. The thing is that sparsity can't be copied bit perfect. The file will just be made sparse on the target, but in a way the system seems fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good and detailed answer on rsync FAQ page found at https://sanitarium.net/rsyncfaq/#differentsizes

There are multiple reasons why source and target may have different sizes:

- excludes
- directory size due to varying disk space allocation (by design and results in target or source being only slightly smaller)
- hard links (1-10% difference)
- sparse files (>10% difference)
- differences in filesystem types, block sizes, file slack overhead, etc.
- df uses binary units (power of 2) while rsync uses decimal units (power of 1000)
- lastly, comparing source and target sizes isn't always reliable and thus checksum verification on files is a much better measure of whether source and target are identical or not

Answer (score 1):

2 gig of missing data is significant.  If the size grew by 2G then there would be some easy explanations: hard links turned into duplicate files, files with holes turned into fully-fleshed out files, and so on. Those are perfectly reasonable explanations.

However since the new size is smaller, you should do a comparison to see what changed.  You don't want to be in a situation where 5 months from now you realize something is wrong and you don't have a valid backup.

Backups aren't important.  Restores are important.  We don't know if a restore will work unless we validate the backup.

For a small number of files you could do `diff -r /mnt/RAIDVault /mnt/RAIDVault-BACKUP`. However if that stops mid-way, it can't be restarted from where it left off.

For a large number of files, I recommend calculating the hashes of all the files and look for differences.  This way if the process stops or breaks, you can continue without much difficulty.

Here's a program that will generate md5 hashes of all files in a directory:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

# md5tree: Output file data information for comparison

use Digest::MD5;
use File::Find ();

# Default to "." unless things are speced on the cmd line.
if ($#ARGV == -1) {
        @DIRS = ( '.' );
} else {
        @DIRS = @ARGV;
}

&File::Find::finddepth(\&wanted, @DIRS);

exit;

sub wanted {
    (($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid) = lstat($_)) &&
    -f _ &&
    ((-s _) > 0) &&
    &doit($_, $File::Find::dir, -s _, $mode, $uid, $gid);
}

sub doit {
        my($fn, $dir, $size, $mode, $uid, $gid) = @_;

        return 0 if $fn =~ m/[\r\n]+/;

        open(FILE, "<$fn") or die "Can't open '$dir/$fn': $!";
        binmode(FILE);
        print Digest::MD5->new->addfile(*FILE)->hexdigest, "\t$size\t$uid\t$gid\t$mode\t$dir/$fn\n";

        return 0;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
# md5tree /mnt/RAIDVault-BACKUP >/var/tmp/list.backup
# md5tree /mnt/RAIDVault        >/var/tmp/list.orig
   # NOTE: For these next 2 lines TAB means press the TAB key.
# sort  -t'TAB' -k6 </var/tmp/list.backup >/var/tmp/list.backup.sorted
# sort  -t'TAB' -k6 </var/tmp/list.orig >/var/tmp/list.orig.sorted
# diff /var/tmp/list.orig.sorted /var/tmp/list.backup.sorted
```

I'd be interested in knowing what difference you find!

Comment: 1G is accounted for by VirtualBox disk image files, confirmed with du. Everything else is basically the same size. But, yeah, checksums is a far more reliable method to verify if source and target are actually identical.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I saw this situation the destination copy was on a filesystem with case insensitive filenames.  The master had files called `foo` and `FOO`. The destination considers those filenames to be the same, so the backup process copied `foo` to `foo`, then it copied `FOO` to `foo`. Thus, we lost the original `foo`.  We lost a lot of files that way.

Comment: FYI, both source and target are EXT4.